# Change NSTextField text color with fade animation - Cocoa

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsanimationcontext

I am trying to change `NSTextField` text color with fade animation by using `NSAnimationContext`. But it's not working. Please help me to solve this issue. Thanking you all!

**Code:**

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
 
        label!.animator().textColor = NSColor.black
    }
    
    @IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: NSButton){
        
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup { (context) in
            
            context.duration = 1.0
            label!.animator().textColor = NSColor.red
        }
   }
```

Comment: What does "But it's not working" mean?  What happens when you click on the button?

Comment: @ElTomato, The label text color set to `red`. But without animation. I need to change text color with animation.

Comment: Have two text fields with one changing its alphaValue, the other showing the final text color.

Comment: @ElTomato, Yeah, I will try! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the outline of one possible solution:

- Subclass `NSAnimation`, say with `TextColorAnimation`
- Have the `init` take the `NSTextField` and final `NSColor`
- Override `currentProgress` as per `NSAnimation` docs to (a) call the super implementation and (b) set the intermediate color and `display` the `NSTextField`
- Use `NSColor.blend(...)` to determine the intermediate color
- `start` this `NSAnimation`

You should get a nice smooth color transition. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Update the color and alpha value in the completion handler:

```
@IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: NSButton){
    NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ [self] context in
        context.duration = 1.0
        context.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeOut)
        label.animator().alphaValue = 0.0
        label.animator().textColor = NSColor.black
    }, completionHandler: { [self] in
        NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ [self] context in
            context.duration = 1.0
            context.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeIn)
            label.animator().alphaValue = 1.0
            label.animator().textColor = NSColor.red
        }, completionHandler: {
        })
    })
 }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  it's bit not smooth animation.

Comment: play with CAMediaTimingFunctionName(eg linear, easeIn) or remove the animation block in completion for your desired look.

Comment: Sure, I will try. Thanks for your help :)